[Python][Tkinter text widget] Cursor position not match with the character position
Hi python experts on stack overflow,
I am programing an application with python tkinter text widget for user to deal with input & output information.
I found an error which the "cursor position" will not match with the "last character's" position.
And the gap or width in between cursor and character will increase with the key-in character increasing as the following two screenshots show.
Error sample 01
Error sample 02
The simplified code is as below.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk  #
        

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Text Widget')
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
root.geometry('800x540')

names = ["sample"]


notebook = ttk.Notebook(root,width=780,height=105,)


frame01 = tk.Frame(root, width=780)        
frame01.pack()

notebook.add(frame01,text=names[0])
notebook.place(x=5, y=130) 


text00 = tk.Text(root,bg="black",fg="white",font=(family:="Consolas",size:=12),insertbackground="white") 
text00.insert(tk.END, ">")
text00.focus()
text00.place(x=5,y=280,width = 780,height = 200)

root.mainloop()


(Environments : windows10 ; python 3.12.1 ; interpreter : Spyder)
After debugging, I found that when I remove following two method or widget, the error will disappear.

root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
notebook = ttk.Notebook

I want to know what is the cause for this issue and how to modify the code or structure to fix it?
Thanks.

Cannot reproduce issue in my Windows 11 with Python 3.12.3.

You should update Spyder IDE.

Thank for the reminder. I ran the code with python directly by batch file. The issue is gone. Thanks!!
